# Show that for a DTMC $(X_n)_n$ we have $\mathbb{E}[X_n \mid X_A] = \mathbb{E}[X_n \mid X_a], a := \max(A)$

Tags: probability, markov-chains, conditional-expectation

Starting from only the definition, I would like to show that for any $A\subseteq \{0,\dots,n-1\}$ we have that:
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_n \mid X_A] = \mathbb{E}[X_n \mid X_a],
$$
with $a  := \max(A)$. I think this is possible by employing the law of total expectation and sum over all possible values for the $X_b$ with $b \notin A$, but this becomes pretty messy.

Comment: This follows directly from the definition of the Markov property
$$
\mathbb E[f(X_n)\mid \sigma(X_A)] = \mathbb E[f(X_n)\mid \sigma(X_a)],
$$
with $f(x)=x$.

Comment: Yea with this definition you are right, I'll explain my problem:

It's for a course and the only thing given as definition of a Markov Chain is the property:
$\mathbb{P}\{X_n = x_n \mid X_{n-1} = x_{n-1},\dots, X_0 = x_0\} = \mathbb{P}\{X_n = x_n \mid X_{n-1} = x_{n-1}\}$ and then there is an exercise which requires you to show that if $(X_n)_n$ is markov, also $(X_{kn})_n$ is Markov ( with $k >0$ a natural number). I can show this is the case using the law of total probability but the calculations seem a bit overkill

Comment: Clearly $\{X_{n-1}=x_{n-1}\}\in\sigma(X_{n-1})$ and hence
$$
\mathbb P(X_n=x_n\mid X_{n-1}=x_{n=1}) = \mathbb E[f(X_n)\mid \sigma(X_{n-1})]
$$
with $f(x) = P_{x_{n-1},x_n}$.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and I agree with it, but this is a course I teach (i.e. I supervise the exercises) and the people who follow this course do not have a strong mathematical background, therefore I would like to show that $(X_{kn})_n$ is a Markov Chain without resorting to any "sophisticated" arguments and only using the definition.